# R: Why does dbWriteTable fail when table exists despite 'append = TRUE'

Tags: mysql, r

I'm trying to append new data to a MySQL table that already exists using the `dbWriteTable` method. I've used it in the past without issue however it is now failing because the table already exists. This is despite using `overwrite=FALSE, append=TRUE,`

The code:

```
full_sum_table <- 'mydb.summary'    
dbWriteTable(conn=open_connection, name=full_sum_table, value=summary_data_final, overwrite=FALSE, append=TRUE, row.names=0)

Error in mysqlExecStatement(conn, statement, ...) : 
   RS-DBI driver: (could not run statement: Table 'summary' already exists)
[1] FALSE
Warning message:
In mysqlWriteTable(conn, name, value, ...) :
  could not create table: aborting mysqlWriteTable
```

The first call of this code works fine, but subsequent calls fail.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Environment:

```
  R version 3.0.2
  Packages: DBI (I was using RMySQL but it is not available for 3.0.2)
  MySQL v5.6.14
  OS: Windows Server 7
```

Comment: Seems like a bug that would be better reported to the package maintainer.

Comment: @hadley - I was hoping that it wasn't but given that it was previously working and now isn't perhaps an update has unsettled things. I just did a complete re-install of R and the RMySQL package (in desperation) but I still have the problem.

Comment: Not that this is all that helpful, but I can confirm that the bug also exists for the PostgreSQL connector as well.  I'll try to look into it.  My way around like you, @getting-there, writing to the public schema and then running two additional queries from R where I moved the table into the desired schema and deleted it in public.  Wasteful, but got the job done.

Comment: Do you have an auto-incrementing primary key in the existing table? If yes, have you looked at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26449666/how-do-i-write-data-from-r-to-postgresql-tables-with-an-autoincrementing-primary/26451425?noredirect=1#comment64226381_26451425 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38427757/making-change-to-function-in-r-package-and-installing-on-ubuntu

Comment: if you have an answer, please add it and then mark as accepted

Comment: @cwallenpoole I have edited the question and moved the answer to an answer.

Comment: @getting-there I would mark the answer with a checkbox below. In the future you can answer your own question by posting it as an answer. This makes it easier for those searching with the same problem to find a solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This solution was listed by the author in the question and has been moved here.

It appears the bug/feature only occurs when a full table path is used such as `myDB.temp_table` compared to simply `temp_table`

```
> dbWriteTable(conn=open_connection, name='myDB.temp_table', value=summary_data_final, overwrite=FALSE, append=TRUE, row.names=0)
Error in mysqlExecStatement(conn, statement, ...) : 
  RS-DBI driver: (could not run statement: Table 'temp_table' already exists)
[1] FALSE
Warning message:
In mysqlWriteTable(conn, name, value, ...) :
  could not create table: aborting mysqlWriteTable

> dbWriteTable(conn=open_connection, name='temp_table', value=summary_data_final, overwrite=FALSE, append=TRUE, row.names=0)
[1] TRUE
```

I haven't found this documented anywhere and am surprised that I haven't come across it before.

Comment: Is there any way to write to a non-default schema?

Comment: Also, one more case is that the table name should be in small case - it took me some time to find it out . Obviously by googling only.  Src: https://github.com/r-dbi/RMySQL/issues/82

Answer (score 1):

**Just use this function to insert a row in your table**

```
 insert_row <- function(jconn,table_name,col_data,data){
  dbSendUpdate(jconn,paste0("INSERT INTO ",table_name," (",paste0(col_data,collapse=','),") VALUES ('",paste0(data,collapse="','"),"');"))
  print('data inserted')}
```