# How to write a table in PostgreSQL from R?

Tags: r, postgresql

At present to insert data in a PostgreSQL table I have to create an empty table and then do an `insert into table values ...` along with a dataframe collapsed insto a single string with all the values. It doesn't work for large sized dataframes.

The `dbWtriteTable()` doesn't work for PostgreSQL and gives the following error...

```
Error in postgresqlpqExec(new.con, sql4) : RS-DBI driver: (could not Retrieve the result : ERROR: syntax error at or near "STDIN" LINE 1: COPY "table_1" FROM STDIN
```

I have tried the following hack as suggested in answer to a similar question asked before. Here's the link... [How do I write data from R to PostgreSQL tables with an autoincrementing primary key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26449666/how-do-i-write-data-from-r-to-postgresql-tables-with-an-autoincrementing-primary/26451425?noredirect=1#comment62757555_26451425)

```
body_lines <- deparse(body(RPostgreSQL::postgresqlWriteTable))
new_body_lines <- sub(
  'postgresqlTableRef(name), "FROM STDIN")', 
  'postgresqlTableRef(name), "(", paste(shQuote(names(value)), collapse = ","), ") FROM STDIN")', 
  body_lines,
  fixed = TRUE
)
fn <- RPostgreSQL::postgresqlWriteTable
body(fn) <- parse(text = new_body_lines)
while("RPostgreSQL" %in% search()) detach("package:RPostgreSQL")
assignInNamespace("postgresqlWriteTable", fn, "RPostgreSQL")
```

This hack still doesn't work for me. The `postgresqlWriteTable()` throws exactly the same error...
What exactly is the problem here?

As an alternative I have tried using `dbWriteTable2()` from `caroline` package. And it throws a different error...

```
Error in postgresqlExecStatement(conn, statement, ...) : 
  RS-DBI driver: (could not Retrieve the result : ERROR:  column "id" does not exist in table_1
)
creating NAs/NULLs for for fields of table that are missing in your df
Error in postgresqlExecStatement(conn, statement, ...) : 
  RS-DBI driver: (could not Retrieve the result : ERROR:  column "id" does not exist in table_1
)
```

Is there any other method to write a large dataframe into a table in PostgreSQL directly?

Comment: How large are we talking here? I just successfully wrote an ~800MB 10,000x1,000 data.frame in R to a PostgreSQL table using `RPostgresQL::dbWriteTable()`. It took a while (something approaching an hour I think), but it worked.

Comment: @bgoldst What I meant was `insert into` method fails for large data... the `dbWriteTable()` fails even for a small data (1X1 df) and gives the error as stated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, I'm not sure why `dbWriteTable()` would be failing; there may be some kind of version/protocol mismatch. Perhaps you could try installing the latest versions of R, the RPostgreSQL package, and upgrading the PostgreSQL server on your system, if possible.

Regarding the `insert into` workaround failing for large data, what is often done in the IT world when large amounts of data must be moved and a one-shot transfer is infeasible/impractical/flaky is what is sometimes referred to as *batching* or [*batch processing*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_processing). Basically, you divide the data into smaller chunks and send each chunk one at a time.

As a random example, a few years ago I wrote some Java code to query for employee information from an HR LDAP server which was constrained to only provide 1000 records at a time. So basically I had to write a loop to keep sending the same request (with the query state tracked using [some kind of weird cookie-based mechanism](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/newstuff/paged-results.html)) and accumulating the records into a local database until the server reported the query complete.

Here's some code that manually constructs the SQL to create an empty table based on a given data.frame, and then insert the content of the data.frame into the table using a parameterized batch size. It's mostly built around calls to `paste()` to build the SQL strings, and `dbSendQuery()` to send the actual queries. I also use `postgresqlDataType()` for the table creation.

```
## connect to the DB
library('RPostgreSQL'); ## loads DBI automatically
drv <- dbDriver('PostgreSQL');
con <- dbConnect(drv,host=...,port=...,dbname=...,user=...,password=...);

## define helper functions
createEmptyTable <- function(con,tn,df) {
    sql <- paste0("create table \"",tn,"\" (",paste0(collapse=',','"',names(df),'" ',sapply(df[0,],postgresqlDataType)),");");
    dbSendQuery(con,sql);
    invisible();
};

insertBatch <- function(con,tn,df,size=100L) {
    if (nrow(df)==0L) return(invisible());
    cnt <- (nrow(df)-1L)%/%size+1L;
    for (i in seq(0L,len=cnt)) {
        sql <- paste0("insert into \"",tn,"\" values (",do.call(paste,c(sep=',',collapse='),(',lapply(df[seq(i*size+1L,min(nrow(df),(i+1L)*size)),],shQuote))),");");
        dbSendQuery(con,sql);
    };
    invisible();
};

## generate test data
NC <- 1e2L; NR <- 1e3L; df <- as.data.frame(replicate(NC,runif(NR)));

## run it
tn <- 't1';
dbRemoveTable(con,tn);
createEmptyTable(con,tn,df);
insertBatch(con,tn,df);
res <- dbReadTable(con,tn);
all.equal(df,res);
## [1] TRUE
```

Note that I didn't bother prepending a `row.names` column to the database table, unlike `dbWriteTable()`, which always seems to include such a column (and doesn't seem to provide any means of preventing it).

Comment: Re your final note: `dbWriteTable(..., row.names=F)`

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error while working through [this example](https://www.r-bloggers.com/getting-started-with-postgresql-in-r/).

For me worked:

```
dbWriteTable(con, "cartable", value = df, overwrite = T, append = F, row.names = FALSE)
```

While I have configured a table "cartable" in pgAdmin. So an empty table existed and I had to overwrite that table with values.

Answer (score 0):

So the answer showing batch processing given earlier is 99.99% correct. However, it doesn't work on windows because of a tiny argument required at the 'insertBatch' function.
(was not able to add a comment for the same answer)

The 'shQuote' function requires an argument type = 'cmd2' for it to work.

However, to add an argument there, you need this answer:

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6827299/r-apply-function-with-multiple-parameters][1]

So, the new 'insertBatch' function becomes:

```html
insertBatch <- function(con,tn,df,size=100L) {
  if (nrow(df)==0L) return(invisible());
  cnt <- (nrow(df)-1L)%/%size+1L;
  for (i in seq(0L,len=cnt)) {
    sql <- paste0("insert into \"",tn,"\" values (",do.call(paste,c(sep=',',collapse='),(',lapply(df[seq(i*size+1L,min(nrow(df),(i+1L)*size)),],shQuote,type = 'cmd2'))),");");
    dbSendQuery(con,sql);
  };
  invisible();
};
```