# Permission denied to write a table with dbWriteTable in RPostgreSQL

Tags: r, postgresql, r-dbi, rpostgresql

I've been trying to solve a problem with the **RPostgreSQL** package for quite some time. My code:

```
path_ene <- "C:/Users/omen03/ENE"

nene <- "ene_2010_02_efm.csv"


drv <- dbDriver("PostgreSQL")

con = dbConnect(drv, user="postgres", password="mypassword",
            host="localhost", port=5432, dbname="ENE")

tn = "ene_2010_02_efm";

dbRemoveTable(con,tn);
dbWriteTable(conn = con, name = tn, value = paste0(path_ene,"/",nene),
                                    sep = ",", overwrite = FALSE))
```

When executing the code described above, I throw the following error:

> Error in postgresqlExecStatement (conn, statement, ...):    
>   RS-DBI driver: (could not Retrieve the result: ERROR: 
>   Could not open file Â«C: /Users/omen03/ENE/ene_2010_02_efm.csvÂ» for reading: **Permission denied**
>
> HINT: COPY FROM tells the PostgreSQL server process to read a
>   file. You may want to use a client-side facility such as psql \ copy.
>   ) In addition: Warning message: In postgresqlImportFile (conn, name,
>   value, ...):    could not load data into table

when I try without specifying the file path, it throws me another error

```
dbRemoveTable(con,tn);
dbWriteTable(conn = con, name = tn, value = nene),
                                    sep = ",", overwrite = FALSE))
```

> Error in postgresqlExecStatement (conn, statement, ...):    RS-DBI
>   driver: (could not Retrieve the result: ERROR: could not open file Â
>   «./ ene_2010_02_efmÂ» for reading: **No such file or directory**
>
> HINT:
>   COPY FROM tells the PostgreSQL server process to read a file. You may
>   want to use a client-side facility such as psql \ copy. ) In addition:
>   Warning message: In postgresqlImportFile (conn, name, value, ...):   
>   could not load data into table

**Update:**

Taking into account the error message, I decided to use sql directly to insert the csv values in each of the tables in the database. For that I used a couple of functions

```
createEmptyTable <- function(con,tn,df) {
  sql <- paste0("create table \"",tn,"\" (",paste0(collapse=',','"',names(df),'" ',sapply(df[0,],postgresqlDataType)),");");
  dbSendQuery(con,sql);
  invisible();
};
```

Taken from: [How to write a table in PostgreSQL from R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37651470/how-to-write-a-table-in-postgresql-from-r)

and

```
#tn: Table name
#c_names: column names of each table (a list) 
#source: The path to each csv files

insert_data = function(tn, source){
  sql = paste0('COPY ',tn,' FROM \'',paste0(path_ene,'\\',source),'\' DELIMITER \',\' CSV HEADER')
  dbSendQuery(con, sql);
}


insert_data(tn[1], paste0(path_ene, "/",nene[1]))
```

Anyway, I still get a very similar error.

> Error in postgresqlExecStatement (conn, statement, ...):    RS-DBI
>   driver: (could not Retrieve the result: ERROR: Could not open file Â
>   «C: /Users/omen03/ENE/ene_2010_02_efm.csvÂ» for reading: Permission
>   denied HINT: COPY FROM tells the PostgreSQL server process to read a
>   file. You may want to use a client-side facility such as psql \ copy.
>   )

My session info:

> R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05) Platform: **x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)**
>   Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18362)
>
> Matrix products: default
>
> locale: [1] LC_COLLATE=Spanish_Chile.1252  LC_CTYPE=Spanish_Chile.1252
>   LC_MONETARY=Spanish_Chile.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                   [5]
>   LC_TIME=Spanish_Chile.1252
>
> attached base packages: [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils
>   datasets  methods   base
>
> other attached packages:  [1] RPostgreSQL_0.6-2  DBI_1.0.0
>   foreign_0.8-71     captioner_2.2.3    kableExtra_1.1.0   wordcloud_2.6
>   tidytext_0.2.2     gridExtra_2.3       [9] gtable_0.3.0
>   readstata13_0.9.2  RColorBrewer_1.1-2 ggrepel_0.8.1      pbapply_1.4-2
>   srvyr_0.3.6        data.table_1.12.6  lubridate_1.7.4    [17]
>   stringi_1.4.3      forcats_0.4.0      stringr_1.4.0      dplyr_0.8.3
>   purrr_0.3.3        readr_1.3.1        tidyr_1.0.0        tibble_2.1.3 
>   [25] ggplot2_3.2.1      tidyverse_1.3.0
>
> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):  [1] httr_1.4.1
>   jsonlite_1.6      viridisLite_0.3.0 splines_3.6.1     modelr_0.1.5
>   assertthat_0.2.1  cellranger_1.1.0  sessioninfo_1.1.1  [9]
>   pillar_1.4.3      backports_1.1.5   lattice_0.20-38   glue_1.3.1
>   digest_0.6.23     rvest_0.3.5       colorspace_1.4-1  htmltools_0.4.0 
>   [17] Matrix_1.2-17     survey_3.36       pkgconfig_2.0.3   broom_0.5.2
>   haven_2.2.0       scales_1.1.0      webshot_0.5.2     generics_0.0.2
>   [25] withr_2.1.2       lazyeval_0.2.2    cli_2.0.0
>   survival_2.44-1.1 magrittr_1.5      crayon_1.3.4      readxl_1.3.1
>   evaluate_0.14     [33] tokenizers_0.2.1  janeaustenr_0.1.5 fs_1.3.1
>   fansi_0.4.0       nlme_3.1-140      SnowballC_0.6.0   xml2_1.2.2
>   tools_3.6.1       [41] hms_0.5.2         mitools_2.4
>   lifecycle_0.1.0   munsell_0.5.0     reprex_0.3.0      compiler_3.6.1
>   rlang_0.4.2       grid_3.6.1        [49] rstudioapi_0.10
>   rmarkdown_1.18    R6_2.4.1          knitr_1.26        zeallot_0.1.0
>   parallel_3.6.1    Rcpp_1.0.3        vctrs_0.2.1       [57]
>   dbplyr_1.4.2      tidyselect_0.2.5  xfun_0.11

Comment: The ability to bulk-load a file relies on the server having direct access to the file itself. Oddly, when I see the look at for [`postgresqlImportFile`](https://github.com/tomoakin/RPostgreSQL/blob/f93cb17cf584d57ced5045a46d16d2bfe05a2769/RPostgreSQL/R/PostgreSQLSupport.R#L520), it looks as if the local R function expects the file to be *local* (i.e., uses `read.table` on it) **and** tells the server to `copy from` a file that (to me) it has always expected to be *server-local*. Perhaps it assumes the client and server are on the same filesystem (obviously not often the case).

Comment: I tried using the copy command directly (see the update), as the error message suggests, but I'm still having problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the answer by looking for the problem of directly importing data into postgresql. It was enough to change the configuration of the folder containing the .csv files.

I reproduce this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22486389/4950935) that was the one I finally used.

> - Right click the folder containing the data file(s) that permission    was denied to and then click Properties.
> - In the Folder's Properties    window, select the Security tab.
> - Click the Edit button. In the    "Permissions for the folder" window that opened, click the Add...    button.
> - Type Everyone into the "Enter the object names to select"    text area box.
> - Click OK and the window will close.