# making change to function in R package and installing on Ubuntu

Tags: r, postgresql, ubuntu, devtools

Short question: I want to edit the `postgresqlWriteTable` function in the `RPostgreSQL` package and install it on R running on an Ubuntu machine.

**Long explanation:**

The root of my problem is that I am trying to write to a postgres table with an auto-incrementing primary key column from R using `dbWriteTable` from `RPostgreSQL` package.

I read this post: [How do I write data from R to PostgreSQL tables with an autoincrementing primary key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26449666/how-do-i-write-data-from-r-to-postgresql-tables-with-an-autoincrementing-primary/26451425?noredirect=1#comment64226381_26451425) which suggested a fix to my problem by changing the function `postgresqlWriteTable` in the `RPostgreSQL` package. It works when I interactively use `fixInNamespace` in OSX environment and edit the function.

Unfortunately I have to run my script on an AWS instance running R on Ubuntu. I have `RPostgreSQL` installed at this location on my machine: `/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/RPostgreSQL` . I installed it by invoking `R CMD install RPostgreSQL_0.4-1.tar.gz`

Now I am trying to find the function `postgresqlWriteTable`. It is supposed to be in the file `PostgreSQLSupport.R` . I have searched the whole library - there is no such file.

I realized that on my local machine in the OSX Finder , when I unzip the tar.gz package folder, I can see the file `PostgreSQLSupport.R` where I am supposed to change the function.

So I changed the function. Then I removed the installed RPostgreSQL from my Ubuntu machine and copied the new folder (from my local machine) into my Ubuntu machine and tried to use `devtools` to install the package as suggested in the post here: [Loading an R Package from a Custom directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5339796/loading-an-r-package-from-a-custom-directory)

here's what happened:

```
> library("devtools")
> install("/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/RPostgreSQL")
Error: Can't find '/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/RPostgreSQL'.
> install("RPostgreSQL", "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/RPostgreSQL")
Installing RPostgreSQL
'/usr/lib/R/bin/R' --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --no-restore --quiet  \
  CMD INSTALL '/datasci/nikhil/RPostgreSQL'  \
  --library='/usr/local/lib/R/site-library' --install-tests 

* installing *source* package ‘RPostgreSQL’ ...
file ‘R/PostgreSQLSupport.R’ has the wrong MD5 checksum
ERROR: 'configure' exists but is not executable -- see the 'R Installation and Administration Manual'
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/RPostgreSQL’
Error: Command failed (1)
```

I am at my wit's end !

Comment: @dirk.eddelbuettel Do you want to get in on this since you're one of the contributors?

Comment: Please also consider [contacting the package authors](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rpostgresql.html) and perhaps [filing an issue](https://code.google.com/archive/p/rpostgresql/) (though that page looks rather inactive) in case you think your adjustment could benefit other users without breaking current functionality.

Comment: honestly I'm not advanced enough to know that but @dirk.eddelbuettel is one of the contributors to `RPostgreSQL` and he has been tagged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Copy the pacakge `.tar.gz` file to the AWS machine.
2. Unpack this file so you have a directory structure.
3. Edit the function inside the file and save your changes.
4. You may also have to increase the version number in the `DESCRIPTION` file.
5. Use `devtools::build` to create a new `.tar.gz` file.
6. Install this updated version of the package.

Comment: Can I make the change and build locally, then move .tar.gz to Ubuntu machine and install?